# What is the default value of members of a char array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, char, default

Say I create a `char` array, and I assume the char array is empty. If I check the value of the first element in the array (`arr[0]`), what would be the result of this expression?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: 'I assume the char array is empty' -- What do you mean by this?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by 'I initialize a char array'? If you initialized it, then it will have the value of the initializer, but I suspect that you don't really mean "initialize". You could resolve some questions (and maybe avoid the atrociously bad answers below) but posting your actual code.

Comment: You need to add more detail to your original post, like the result of printing out the value, and what you expected. What languages did you study before? I am asking this, because I'm convinced with all the Python, Perl, Ruby, and Scala knowledge out there, some folks learning C may think something special happens when you test for a value in an array

Comment: Downvote because @user1723575 could easily have answered this question himself by trying it or a quick google search (or stack overflow search for that matter). I don't see why there are 5 answers to this trivial question.

Comment: I googled "char array initial value" today (in 2014). This stack overflow question was the first hit. I almost thought it had been a waste of my time coming here because the question had been downvoted and "closed as not a real question".  Fortunately, John Bode's answer gave me the answer I was looking for.

Comment: I agree with @TimGradwell, the answer below helped and I understood what the user was asking. The asker could have used some help by the community to make the question clearer. When you're new to the programming, you may not have the vocabulary to articulate what you need (hence question edit-ability by community).

Answer (score 29):

It depends on where and how the array is declared.

If the array is declared at file scope (outside of any function), or is declared `static`, and does not have an explicit initializer, then the contents of the array will be initialized to 0.

If the array is declared at block scope (within a function or block) and is not declared `static`, and does not have an explicit initializer, then the contents of the array are *indeterminate* (essentially, garbage values, some of which may be trap representations).

If the array has been explicitly initialized, then it contains whatever was in the initializer.

**EDIT**

In response to the comments below, note that you shouldn't rely on implicit initialization for block-scope variables.  If you need a block-scope array to be zeroed out on creation, use an initializer:

```
char foo[N] = {0};
```

When there are fewer elements in the initializer than there are in the array, elements in the array corresponding to elements in the initializer will be set to the value specified; all remaining entries will be implicitly initialized as if they were declared `static`.

In the example above, this means that the first element of `foo` is explicitly set to `0`, while all the remaining elements are implicitly set to `0`.

Comment: In any case, it's bad form to rely on it. Variables which must be zero should be initialised to zero, explicitly.

Comment: @John Bode: what you're saying is all factual - I'm just afraid the OP's takeaway might be "Oh - I should make all my variables static, so I don't have to initialize them."  A better answer might have touched (however briefly) on issues of "definition" vs. "declaration", or *why* a variable should be automatic vs. static vs. allocated from the heap.  I agree with jforberg.  IMHO...

Comment: I think you can just say `char foo[N] = {};`.

Comment: I'd like to clarify that an indeterminate value can also be 0.  This would mean that if foo[0] was default initialized as 0 without an explicit initializer, foo would indeed have 0 length.

Answer (score 3):

If it's an `auto` variable, it will be filled with junk unless you explicitly initialize it, so there is no default value. `arr[0]` will likely contain a seemingly random value until explicitly changed to contain something else.

Of course, if you initialized the array (meaning that you filled the array with initial values explicitly using something like `memset()` or a `for` loop or a function call or whatever other means), you'll get exactly what you expect: the value with which you initialized it.

Do note though the difference between declaration and initialization.

```
void f(void) {
    int x;  // (1)
    x = 10; // (2)
}
```

At **(1)**, you're declaring an `auto` integer variable. It has an undefined value right now (junk). At **(2)**, you're initializing the variable. It now has the value of `10`.

Of course, declaration and initialization can both be done at once:

```
void f(void) {
    int x = 10;
}
```

The same thing is true for arrays:

```
void f(void) {
    int x[2];  // x contains 2 junk values, so x[0] == junk
    x[0] = 1;  // x contains { 1, junk },   so x[0] == 1
    x[1] = 2;  // x contains { 1, 2 },      so x[0] == 1
}
```

or, to declare and initialize it:

```
void f(void) {
    int x[2] = { 1, 2 };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Never expect any variable to have any certain value when you first initialize it unless you specify it explicitly.  It will be filled with random stuff unless you set it yourself.

Comment: I compared its value with '\0' ex: arr[0]=='\0' and it turns out to be true, I assume this is because that space in memory is really empty but in the case that it has something else I would be wrong,  right?

Comment: Yes, you never really know what may or may not already be there.

Answer (score -2):

when initiate array. your are allocating a static memory. and then you will get the values of allocated memory so it's random values

if you want set the whole array to 0 then (According to **Hunter McMillen** Remark)

```
char arr[size] = { 0 }
```

or use `memset()` function

```
memset(arr,0,sizeof_your_arr);
```

Comment: You can also do: `char arr[size] = { 0 }`