# What is the default value of an element of an uninitialized character array?

Tags: arrays, c, c-strings

here's a code I wrote

```
    int main(){
    char arr[50][*];
    arr[0][0]=1;
    if(arr[0][1]){
    printf("%d",arr[0][0]);}
```

If I am putting 1 as *, there is no output.
but anything greater than 1 in the array size would result in 1 output.that means when I am declaring array size the elements are occupied by some value.

now, my actual need is to write a condition if loop (example)

```
if(arr[0][1]!='null') // or '0',false,undefined, etc
```

but I am confused what is there in that empty but declared element, because the above is not working.

Comment: you have not initialized the `arr`, so cannot say what gets printed

Comment: This question has explained answer for your question [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12750265/what-is-the-default-value-of-members-of-a-char-array-in-c)

Comment: please properly ident your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

doing(while declaring),

```
char arr[50][2]={0}  //or whatever the size of 2nd dimension other than 2
```

this will replace all elements(100 in this case) with 0.

So, according to my necessity,I can do

```
if(arr[0][1] != 0)
```

for checking if that element is undefined by me.
**this example works when your input doesn't contain 0, if it does replcae all elements with something else and also the condition too**

Answer (score 4):

There is no default value.

For an object defined inside a function without the `static` keyword, the initial value is garbage.

You can't test an object to determine whether it's been initialized or not. You have to write your code to avoid reading any object's value before it's been set.

Comment: actually I was trying to print an array whose size I don't know

Comment: @mr.loop The code in your question doesn't show an array whose size you don't know. I can only answer the question you asked.

Comment: let me rephrase that. I wanted to print an array whose number of initialized or defined elements I don't know. anyways, i got the answer.